# Can I keep my propane tank valve open?

Tags: fireplace, heater, patio, propane

I just bought a new [Portable Fireplace](https://www.wayfair.com/Orren-Ellis--Belle-Stone-Propane-Fire-Pit-Table-ORIS1752-L327-K~ORIS1752.html?refid=GX103455936643-ORIS1752_33427501&device=c&ptid=493410742704&network=g&targetid=aud-354999624391:pla-493410742704&channel=GooglePLA&ireid=63676141&PiID%5B%5D=33427501&gclid=Cj0KCQjwtMvlBRDmARIsAEoQ8zRf-A6-IGF3O5CXr5uzyT6L5sm3eHeZzRBk20zLtm558skdR6-p7S0aAgCfEALw_wcB&piid=33427502) and it can contain the propane tank inside it. I also bought some firestones to put in the fire area. The only problem with this is that if I want to turn on/off the fireplace then I need to lift up the fire place and then turn the propane tank valve on/off.

Which is do-able but a bit of a hassle. I was thinking to keep the propane tank valve always on. If I do that, I can still rely on fireplace valve to turn the heat on/off. The only potential problem with this is that my propane tank valve would be perpetually on.

This leaves me with one question: what can potentially happen if the tank is on. is it going to leak the gas or is it plain out hazardous to safety?

Comment: If you do so, you should implement a maintenance program.  If the propane line were to be punctured or involved in a fire, it would take much less of an incident to fully discharge the tank than if the tank's own valve was closed.  Better to rely on a steel tank than a rubber tube.  You could also consider adding an access hatch or a remote valve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

Either you make the tank valve available with an access hole or similar,

Or you install an external valve, but this would defeat the logic of having the isolation valve as close as possible to the tank with no intermediate piping.

Making alterations to the gas system may invalidate any insurance coverage unless you have it inspected by a relevant authority - depends on the location ...  Lots of regulations for gas systems as the possibility of a big bang is high :)

Answer (score 2):

It's best to close the valve on the propane tank, and I'm sure the instructions tell you to do that just like any other fire pit or BBQ grill that I have seen.  The valves on the fire pit are outside and exposed to the weather, and they are more likely to leak (in my opinion).

That said, many people do leave them on all the time, accidentally or on purpose.  To answer the other part of your question, a propane leak from a tank like that outside doesn't pose a lot of risk.  The gas dissipates into the air so it's not going to suffocate or poison anyone.  Also, propane doesn't burn unless it's mixed with the right amount of air.  Too little or too much and it won't ignite.  Theres a small chance that just the right amount of propane could build up in the box where the tank is, and that could cause a small explosion that would damage the fire pit.

Now, all that is to simply say that it's not nearly as dangerous as a leak in your house, but there is risk.  At the very least, you just paid $20 for a propane tank that you'll use once because of a small leak.  Turn it off when it won't be used for a while.